# Android title without actionbar

Tags: android, title

[image]I have a bit of a riddle:

I have an AndroidApplication.
The title is visible, getTitle returns the correct String.
However, getActionBar returns null.
If this be so, what is then the parentview on which the title is shown (and how do I change its color)?
I of course googled TitleBar but this always returns me answers to "actionbar" which is not what I am looking for.
There is a screenshot.
"Priscus" (white Letters on grey ground) is the title. 
Now I want to change the grey to another color.
Is there a way to do it?
I do not really need an actionbar, options and such, I only need another color at this one place.

Comment: For this you have to define your title in custom layout and try include title layout in each activity layout xml.

Comment: a photo of the layout please?

Comment: I am just making a snapshot (emulator still loading) but why do you want my xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, getActionBar returns null.

In part, that is because you have chosen to use a theme based on `Theme`, rather than one based on `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.Material`, based upon your screenshot. There is no action bar with `Theme`, as `Theme` pre-dates the action bar, introduced over four years ago in Android 3.0.

> what is then the parentview on which the title is shown

That lies outside the scope of the Android SDK, and I am not aware that it can be reached even via unreliable script-kiddie approaches.

> and how do I change its color

You don't. The long-since-discontinued title bar, as shown in your screenshot, always looks that way.

> I do not really need an actionbar, options and such

That may be true. However, users are going to interpret your ancient UI theme as a sign that you are not updating and maintaining the app, since it looks like it has not been touched in four years. This may reduce interest in your app, if it is being distributed to all comers through a distribution channel like the Play Store.

Comment: I do not want to sell it anyway.

Comment: @user1862770: OK. Then I suggest going with a `.NoTitleBar` or `.NoActionBar` theme (e.g., `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`), and putting your own title across the top of your activities, with whatever color scheme you wish to use.

Comment: hence program around it. I could do that, of course....with a Textview, probably. So I take it what I actually want is not possible.